# TYPO3 11: convert t3 file uri into file identifier

Tags: typo3

How can I convert the TYPO3 file uri `t3://file?uid=54` to be usable for other TYPO3 methods which need a file identifier?
The file uri is returned by a flexform which selects a XML file. This XML file should be read.
However I cannot find a useful API function in the TYPO3 Core.

```
$paramTestFile = 't3://file?uid=54';
$xmlString = GeneralUtility::getURL($paramTestFile);
```

The above code fails for TYPO3 URIs.

The file reference with uid=54 is at "fileadmin/example.xml".
The Filelist backend module shows the details of this file.
However I need this file path also in the PHP code in order to read in the file.

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\LinkHandling\FileLinkHandler;

$fileHandler = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(FileLinkHandler::class);
$fileInfo = $fileHandler->asString($paramTestFile);
```

It is not possible to use `$paramTestFile` in the above example.
The class FileLinkHandler and its method `asString` does exactly the opposite of what I need.

```
$content = @file_get_contents($url);
```

However the absolute file path is needed for the read method . How can I convert the FAL file URI into the file identifier?

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\StorageRepository;

$storageRepository = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(StorageRepository::class);
$defaultStorage = $storageRepository->getDefaultStorage();
$fileInfo = $defaultStorage->getFileByIdentifier($paramTestFileIdentifier);
```

Comment: What exactly would you like to achieve in the end? Get the File object or the file content?

Comment: I would like to get the file object and with this I can read its database record of the FAL table of TYPO3: `sys_file`. Then I would also be able to read the contents of this XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve a `t3://file...` URN use [`TYPO3\CMS\Core\LinkHandling\LinkService::resolve()`](https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/3757e629485a00694ef66c10fca487938ae75aa4/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/LinkHandling/LinkService.php#L70-L86). This method will return an array with a key `file` containing a [`TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileInterface`](https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/3757e629485a00694ef66c10fca487938ae75aa4/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Resource/FileInterface.php#L18-L21). This also works for other URNs but will return another array structure.

Then use the [`getContents()`](https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/3757e629485a00694ef66c10fca487938ae75aa4/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Resource/FileInterface.php#L94-L99) method of the [`FileInterface`](https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/3757e629485a00694ef66c10fca487938ae75aa4/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Resource/FileInterface.php#L18-L21) to finally get the content of the file.

The documentation is not very detailed for this part of the core so I have linked you directly to the related sources.

Comment: This solution works fine. I have implemented it [here](https://github.com/franzholz/watchwords/blob/38bfc7dbefb18fe988ec99887e14433b73777bc9/Classes/Api/BibleWebApi.php#L139-L151)